# Identify part "S8851": apparently input protection

Tags: identification, surge-protection

Could someone identify help identify these please?

I think they're some kind of input protection: they are open-circuit, each from a pin of an RS-422 connector to chassis.

- Labelled "**S8851 / 1.5KE / 24C**"
- Believed to be from around 1985.
- Length 9.5 mm, dia 5 mm.
- Maker's mark appears to be four 5-point stars arranged as follows

  ```
      ★
    ★   ★
      ★
  ```

[image]

Comment: Can you trace the tracks on the PCB to see what each of the ``S8851`` parts are connected to?

Comment: Yes, as I put in the question: each goes from a pin of an RS-422 socket to the chassis.

Answer (score 3):

The 8851 is probably the date code. 1.5ke24C is a [Littelfuse](https://m.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_1_5ke_datasheet.pdf.pdf) part number.

Bidirectional 1500W 24V TVS.

The logo is a relic of some pre-acquisition [manufacturer](https://www.littelfuse.com/about-us/history-and-culture/acquisitions.aspx).

Comment: And being bidirectional explains the lack of a cathode band on the package.

Comment: Perfect! Seems to match exactly, including dimensions.